# PDF printer free

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, hyperlink

I am looking for a PDF printer (i.e. a "virtual printer" producing PDF files, which can be used by any application just like any other printer) which is able to parse `<a href='http://www.foobar.baz'>weblinks</a>`, not only the explicit ones such as `http://www.foobar.baz`, and makes them clickable in the resulting document so the reader can easily follow such links. The software should come free of charge.

P.S.: LibreOffice is not in line with my firm's policy and "Microsoft print to PDF" feature does not accomplish to this task.

Comment: I want something to make a pdf from some other source and, at the same time, import existing links. Don't you have understood? Really?

Comment: OK, now I get it. Your question isn't clear, though - you might want to edit to make it clearer, rather than getting annoyed in comments. This is something Mac can do natively, no additional software required - from any source, web page etc, Print, Save as pdf, all links are clickable. I don't know an equivalent for Windows, sorry.

Comment: Guess we now got what you meant – I've adjusted your question once more and will now cleanup "obsolete comments". I'm no Windows user (I kicked that out 25 years ago and never regretted it), but if it's just about "text documents", LibreOffice includes functionality for PDF export which you might wish to try. It can also read (and write) MS formats and more, so it would work for documents you already have.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Izzy, for your support in better fit editing my question. I am also not a Windows user, I am a lifelong linux user. But I need such tool for my collegues, and LibreOffice is not in line with my firm's policy (ie only MS Office plus AcrobatReaderDC for now). "Microsoft print to PDF" feature does not accomplish to my question.

Comment: @DarioCorrada: if you use "Export as PDF" from inside Microsoft Word (rather than using Windows' "PDF printer"), then links are clickable

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good! So post your comment as an answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu there is such feature!

It's sounds to me somehow disturbing to create a linux virtual machine for only a simple virtual printer. But that's the way I found